# ASP.NET MVC5 with existing Membership database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing ASP.NET Membership database which I have to stick to. I'm developing a new MVC5 website in VS2013 (update 4) using a new MVC website project template. I have modified web.config to ensure the old Membership type of authentication is specified. I have also modified generated [HttpPost]Login action to ensure I login against my Membership database - it logs me in correctly and generates an authentication cookie as required.

However the website still redirects me to the Login page as I'm not authenticated. The Request.IsAuthenticated does show that I'm not authenticated. What am I missing? What are my options?
EDIT:
web.config changes (only changes):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=sql1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mysa;Password=mypw" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="20" name="seAdmin" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
  </authentication>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyCS" applicationName="/seAdmin" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyCS" applicationName="/seAdmin" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <machineKey validationKey="63A7C07B191BA3EF02DD4866C420DCAB81C9FFCCC617DE40ED6E2B89A2FC2BA3FA32C39D183FE0708E9279C14E58318D0C5E171C0AF802F154430679D1778485" decryptionKey="F5B9049DECB8C9A23B1D131E63D2ED5C15FF0AEB3C3E96FC" validation="SHA1" />
</system.web>
```

Login action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

FilterConfig adds a global authorisation attribute

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

            filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "CWA" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough info to receive a good answer, also I don't think migrating from membership to identity is that simple, show us in code what you've changed and also take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Sorry for being not detailed enough. I'm not migrating from Membership to Identity. What I'd like to do is to implement a Membership authentication in MVC 5 using a modified version of the default project template. If such a modification is too complex I'm happy to accept any other idea other than using MVC 4 instead of MVC 5. I'll update my question with code changes.

Comment: Did you delete the "remove" entry from the Modules section of the web.config that removes the FormsAuthentication module IIS?  FYI, FormsAuthentication has nothing to do with Membership.

Comment: To Eric - no, I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some theories as to why it doesn't work, firstly in `web.config` there is a `<system.webServer>` tag, there must be a line for removing `FormsAuthentication`, try commenting it out, or add one again, like so:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

secondly try `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to see it is false too, also are you have any role in your app?

Comment: Thanks very much to Eric and Xellarix, commenting out `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />` solved the issue, I can now login successfully.